# sublime text - plugin for creating automatic start end html comments

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any plugin out there that creates begin, end HTML comments automatically? Like the following.

```
<!-- begin #page -->
<div id="page">
    <!-- begin #header -->
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
</div>
<!-- end #page -->
```

I am tired of commenting these out.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this little snippet that I wrote:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!-- .${1:className} -->
<div class="${1:className}">
    ${2}
</div>
<!-- /.${1:className} -->
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>divc</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

and save it in `Sublime Text #\Packages\User\divc.sublime-snippet`

When you are done, you can use `divc`+`tab` to generate the required snippet

Comment: This should be the accept as from the OP question it looks as though this will achieve the desired effect. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not that i know of but you can create a custom snippet and use it when you like. This will allow you to insert that text without typing it out each time.

For directions check this link:
http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: I think snippet seems to serve my need. But do you know how to fire them easily. Do I always have to go tools > Snippets > (then search for it). (can I prolly bind a short-cut?)

Comment: @BisratTekle, you can launch snippets by pressing tab after writing the snippet "code".

Comment: i think its just like using auto complete... like when you type <html and then hit tab it builds the page out...

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to comment something out, you can just select the content you want to comment and type `ctrl + /` and it will do the trick.

Comment: I don't want to comment the HTML... I want to add supportive comment based on the created blocks.

Comment: that I don't know, maybe create your own like @user2515563 said?

Comment: I think Richard's answer does fit your use case though. In Sublime, if you were to write a new line with `end #page` then hit `Ctrl + /` it would comment out the text you just wrote.

If you generated the markup in Emmet for example, I believe it's a better workflow if you just added the comments as you tabbed through the markup.